# OpenCV SIFT+FLANN multiple matches for single keypoint

Tags: python, opencv, keypoint

I'm trying to match keypoints using open cv.
Specifically, I'm using the "sift" detector and "flann" matcher. My code is based on [cv2's documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d6f/tutorial_feature_flann_matcher.html):

```
detector = cv2.SIFT_create()
matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(indexParams=dict(algorithm=0, trees=5), searchParams=dict(checks=50))
kps1, desc1 = detector.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kps2, desc2 = detector.detectAndCompute(img2, None)
all_matches = matcher.knnMatch(desc1, desc2, 2)

ratio = 0.7
good_matches = []
for m, n in all_matches:
  if m.distance <= ratio * n.distance:
    good_matches.append(m)
```

I noticed than even within the `good_matches` list, I have some keypoints that have more than a single match:

```
extra_matches = dict()
for match in good_matches:
  t_idx = match.trainIdx
  reps = [mch for mch in good_matches if mch.trainIdx == t_idx]
  if len(reps) > 1 and t_idx not in extra_matches.dict():
    extra_matches[t_idx] = reps

print(len(extra_matches))  # not 0
```

I find this weird because I thought that `knnMatch` already yields the 2 best matches. Why would I have more than a single match per keypoint after ratio-pruning the matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure enough, five minutes after posting I found the answer:

`FLANN` does not do cross-checks, which means I will have repeats of the 2nd keypoints but no repeats for the 1st keypoints (verified in my code as well).
The best practice if you need cross-check with `FLANN` is to implement your own cross-check or use `FLANN` to get a subset of descriptors and then use `BFMatcher`'s cross-check option.

Here are some other sources of information: [[1]](https://answers.opencv.org/question/109989/flann-tree-cross-check/), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60260567/equivalent-parameter-unique-in-sift-matching-between-flann-matcher-in-opencv-a)